# Convert R 3D array to stacked matrix

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, data-conversion

I have a 3D R array, e.g.:

```
a <- array(1:27, dim = c(3,3,3))
```

How can I (efficiently) convert this into a matrix in which the 3rd dimension is bound / stacked below each other, i.e.:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    4    7
 [2,]    2    5    8
 [3,]    3    6    9
 [4,]   10   13   16
 [5,]   11   14   17
 [6,]   12   15   18
 [7,]   19   22   25
 [8,]   20   23   26
 [9,]   21   24   27
```

I can clumsily achieve this with:

```
rbind(a[,,1], a[,,2], a[,,3])
```

but this is not generalizable well if I have many entries in the 3rd dimension (except with looping).
There must be a more elegant way to achieve this, but I could not find it. [Ideas like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921426/converting-array-to-matrix-in-r)

```
apply(a, 3, rbind)
apply(a, 3, c)
```

create a matrix, but the 3rd dimension simply become the columns. I want to keep the 2D matrices of the first 2 dimensions and just bind them together. I am aware this will mess up the indices, but we can disregard this for my use case.

I would be especially happy about a base R solution, but am also interested if this can be achieved with a (lightweight) package.

Edit:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639851/3193733) to a [seemingly unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639244/loop-through-array-in-r) provided a useful hint. This approach seems to achieve the desired result:

```
matrix(aperm(a, c(1, 3, 2)), nrow = dim(a)[1] * dim(a)[3])
```

Are there other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `aperm` we transpose an array by permuting its dimensions and optionally resizing it:

```
y <- aperm(a, c(1, 3, 2))
dim(y) <- c(prod(dim(a)[-2]), dim(a)[2])

y
```

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    4    7
 [2,]    2    5    8
 [3,]    3    6    9
 [4,]   10   13   16
 [5,]   11   14   17
 [6,]   12   15   18
 [7,]   19   22   25
 [8,]   20   23   26
 [9,]   21   24   27
```